How can I make a table that has position:absolute to expand and fill available spaces in its container?
I have a table inside a div. The table has position: absolute with inset defined:
https://jsfiddle.net/dp4k9oc1/
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

table {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

label {
  background: red;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

It looks like this:

How can I make the table's width and height to fill the div, and still respect the inset? E.g. something like this:


<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>hello</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


table {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: calc(100% - 100px); /* 100% minus the horizontal inset */
  height: calc(100% - 100px); /* 100% minus the vertical inset */
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative; /* Ensure the div is the containing block */
}

label {
  background: red;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

